# git larger file not pushing to repo

Tags: json, git, github

I am doing an ai project wrote details to a json file
came into this error

**remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data.json is 113.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage **

I've deleted the file from git hub and have removed it locally but still running into this problem tried to set up git lfs as in the documentation but still same error

Looked at documentation
I did git rm -f data.json
Also git unstaged the file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: Did you add the file in one commit and then remove it in another commit? If that is the case you are actually still trying to push the file to github because when pushing you are pushing the entire history of your branch, not just what is on it now.